# Error compiling kotlin in Windows / Android Studio

Tags: android, windows, gradle, kotlin

This project it's an open source project, when I try it in Mac, it works great, but when I try to compile it in Windows I get the following error

[image]

I only have this line in build.gradle.kts

```
../../buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
```

[image]
If i open a new project with Kotlin in Android Studio I have no problems... any idea?

Error log:

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'C:\prueba21\candroid\buildSrc\build.gradle.kts' line: 1
Script compilation errors:

  Line 1: ../../buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
          ^ Expecting an element

  Line 1: ../../buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
            ^ Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

2 errors
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.withKotlinCompiler(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:507)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.compileScriptBody(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:253)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.access$compileScriptBody(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler$loadScriptBodyClass$2.invoke(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:240)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler$loadScriptBodyClass$2.invoke(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptClassloadingCache.loadScriptClass(KotlinScriptClassloadingCache.kt:64)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.loadScriptBodyClass(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:236)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.executeScriptBody(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:132)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.prepareAndExecuteScriptBody(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:127)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.access$prepareAndExecuteScriptBody(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler$compile$1.invoke(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:107)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler$compile$1.invoke(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler$asKotlinScript$1.invoke(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:121)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler$asKotlinScript$1.invoke(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$createScriptAction$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:58)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$createScriptAction$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:33)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPlugin.apply(KotlinScriptPlugin.kt:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:64)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:667)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:136)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:261)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSrcUpdateFactory.build(BuildSrcUpdateFactory.java:50)
    at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSrcUpdateFactory.create(BuildSrcUpdateFactory.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder.buildBuildSrc(BuildSourceBuilder.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder.access$000(BuildSourceBuilder.java:37)
    at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder$2.call(BuildSourceBuilder.java:75)
    at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder$2.call(BuildSourceBuilder.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:350)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:340)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:120)
    at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder.createBuildSourceClasspath(BuildSourceBuilder.java:72)
    at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder.buildAndCreateClassLoader(BuildSourceBuilder.java:58)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:109)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:48)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoaderFactory$1.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoaderFactory.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.java:45)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$LoadBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:240)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.loadSettings(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ScriptCompilationException(errors=[ScriptCompilationError(message=Expecting an element, location=C:\Users\barce\.gradle\caches\4.6\gradle-kotlin-dsl\7fkgaz5gvkj5r4mfp63xbl2li\build.gradle.kts (1:1)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line), location=C:\Users\barce\.gradle\caches\4.6\gradle-kotlin-dsl\7fkgaz5gvkj5r4mfp63xbl2li\build.gradle.kts (1:3))])
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.KotlinCompilerKt.compileKotlinScriptToDirectory(KotlinCompiler.kt:80)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.CachingKotlinCompiler$compileScriptTo$$inlined$run$lambda$1.invoke(CachingKotlinCompiler.kt:143)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.CachingKotlinCompiler$compileScriptTo$$inlined$run$lambda$1.invoke(CachingKotlinCompiler.kt:72)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.CachingKotlinCompiler.withProgressLoggingFor(CachingKotlinCompiler.kt:203)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.CachingKotlinCompiler.compileScriptTo(CachingKotlinCompiler.kt:139)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.CachingKotlinCompiler.access$compileScriptTo(CachingKotlinCompiler.kt:72)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.CachingKotlinCompiler$compileScript$cacheDir$1.invoke(CachingKotlinCompiler.kt:117)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.CachingKotlinCompiler$compileScript$cacheDir$1.invoke(CachingKotlinCompiler.kt:72)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.cache.ScriptCacheKt$sam$Action$c91fa422.execute(ScriptCache.kt)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:107)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:85)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:200)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:190)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:83)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:141)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:61)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:34)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:92)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:124)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.cache.ScriptCache.cacheDirFor(ScriptCache.kt:51)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.cache.ScriptCache.cacheDirFor$default(ScriptCache.kt:43)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.CachingKotlinCompiler.cacheDirFor(CachingKotlinCompiler.kt:157)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.CachingKotlinCompiler.compileScript(CachingKotlinCompiler.kt:115)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.CachingKotlinCompiler.compileScriptBlock(CachingKotlinCompiler.kt:92)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler$compileScriptBody$1.invoke(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:254)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler$compileScriptBody$1.invoke(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.withKotlinCompiler(KotlinBuildScriptCompiler.kt:206)
    ... 139 more
```

Comment: would you share your build.gradle.kts ?

Comment: Post the actual error logs

Comment: edited to add error log and picture with build.gradle

Comment: in fact this is the project, you have to open candroid https://github.com/instructure/instructure-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this project uses symbolic links, which are not supported on Windows. To get past this immediate problem, you can copy build.gradle.kts from ../../buildSrc/build.gradle.kts to overwrite the file which contains this single line, but it's likely that you will encounter more problems later on.

Comment: I will try this afternoon! Thanks in advance!